# How to deal with the query timeout due to large amount of unsequence file in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I found that when the `unsequence` file in Apache IoTDB is relatively large, some queries proceeded slower and exceeded 60s (the default query_timeout_threshold time) many times, but they are not terminated. Wonder what should I do to speed up these query process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `unsequence` files will affect query performance, but Apache IoTDB can efficiently deal with this problem. You can enable the cross-space merging function to merge the `unsequence` data files into sequential storage.